# Density of a Random Variable

Tags: probability

> A point is chosen uniformly at random inside the triangle with vertices at $(0, 0), (0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$, meaning that the probability that the point lies in a certain region inside the triangle is proportional to the area of that region. Let $X$ and $Y$ be respectively the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point and let $Z = \max{\{X, Y\} }$. Compute the density of
>   $Z$.

MY WORK:
I drew the triangle out and its of height and base length $1$ so its area is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I know $W=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is a random variable from class.

I begin like all the examples $P(Z \leq a)=P(\max{\{X,Y\}}\leq a)$

now, on the picture, if we draw the $x=y$ line I know that the area of the triangle where $y>x$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, and vice versa.

MY ATTEMPT TO FOLLOW USER @Jsevillamol's HINT BELOW:

$$F_Z(a)=P(Z\leq z)=P(\max{\{X,Y\}} \leq a)$$

If $a \leq \frac{1}{2}$ we see that the area of the region is a square, as noted by user @Jsevillamol below (thank you).

If $a > \frac{1}{2}$ then we see that the area of the region is a square with a corner cut out so I get

$$P(Z \leq a)=\begin{cases} \frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{2}} \quad 0<a\leq\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{a^2-\frac{(2a-1)^2}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} \quad 1/2 <a \leq 1\end{cases}$$

Thus we have to take a derivative so we get

$$f_Z:= \begin{cases} 4a \quad 0 <a\leq \frac{1}{2} \\ 4-4a \quad \frac{1}{2}<a\leq 1 \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let us work through this example together.

We want to find the relative size of the region of the triangle where $Z = max(X,Y)$ is less than equal some $a$.

If $a\le 1/2$, the region is a square, and its area is easy to compute.

If however $a > 1/2$, the region is a square missing a corner which we need to take into account. This corner has the shape of a isosceles right triangle and its common side is $a-(1-a)=2a-1$ long.

Doing the calculations carefully we arrive at:

$$
P(Z\le a) = \frac{\text{area where $Z\le a$ }}{\text{area of whole triangle}}
\begin{cases}
\frac{a^2}{1/2} \text{ if $a \le 1/2$} \\
\frac{a^2 - \frac{(2a-1)^2}{2}}{1/2}  \text{ if $a > 1/2$}
\end{cases}
$$

Can you finish the calculation and compute the PDF on your own?

Comment: If $a \leq \frac{1}{2}$ then wouldn't our region have area $a-a^2$?

Comment: and of area $a-a^2/2-3/8$ when $a>1/2$?

Comment: AHHH never mind, the max{x,y} has to be less than a, not just x like what I was doing thank you

Comment: @jello No problem. Do not forget to accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: I do not understand the second part of your answer and when you integrate this over the domain we do not get 1

Comment: @jello I had forgotten to divide the area of the corner by $2$. I have added an explanation too.

Comment: THANK YOU for your excellent help.